# Find $\gcd (3 + \sqrt{13},\ 2 + 5\sqrt{13})$ in $\mathbb Z[(1+\sqrt{13})/2]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

My task is find $\gcd (3 + \sqrt{13},\ 2 + 5\sqrt{13})$ in $\mathbb Z[(1+\sqrt{13})/2]$.

Can you give me some advice?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: [Worked Example of Euclidean Algorithm](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/the-euclidean-algorithm)

Comment: Your question seems to have gotten a downvote and a vote to put it on hold. I don't know for sure, but I suspect that the voter(s) would like to see you provide some context: background information, your own thoughts etc. For example, do you know the class number here (if $h>1$ then gcd may not exist as an element)? What other related theory has been covered, and/or have you seen similar examples done, and why you are uncertain whether the same method would not work here?

Comment: Please edit your post and add a few such things. They also serve to dispel the thoughts that you might try and outsource homework here. This may sound strange, but we have come to expect such things from questions on this site - a long story. **Edit:** Ok, I checked your history on the site a bit. You seem to know the drill. Sorry, if I sounded a bit too patronizing.

Comment: @lioness99a: Do you know that this ring is a Euclidean domain? Otherwise that link is kinda useless.

Comment: Ok. [$h=1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one), but leaving to others to check whether the ring is Euclidean or even norm-Euclidean. Anyway you are looking for a generator of the ideal generated by $3+\sqrt{13}$ and $2+5\sqrt{13}$. You can easily produce four generators of that ideal **as an abelian group**, and then run the usual algorithm to reduce that to two. Then try and see whether you can identify a single element that generates that as an ideal. When you know the index of the ideal, calculations with norms should be a good guide.

Comment: Do you know about the computation of norms? It doesn't always get you all the way to an answer, but it can really light the way. e.g., $N(3 + \sqrt{13}) = -4$ and $N(2 + 5 \sqrt{13}) = -321$. This suggests the two numbers are coprime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\text{Let}\;\;R &= \mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{13})/2]\\[4pt]
a &=3 + \sqrt{13}\\[4pt]
b &=2 + 5\sqrt{13}\\[8pt]
\end{align*}
and suppose that $d \in R$ is a common divisor of $a,b$.

By definition,
\begin{align*}
& N(a) = a\bar{a} = \left(3 + \sqrt{13}\right)\left(3 - \sqrt{13}\right) = -4\\[4pt]
& N(b) = b\bar{b} = \left(2 + 5\sqrt{13}\right)\left(2 - 5\sqrt{13}\right)= -321\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so in the ring $R$, we have
\begin{align*}
&d\,{\mid}\,a\;\;\text{and}\;\;a\,{\mid}\,(-4)\implies d\,{\mid}\,(-4)\\[4pt]
&d\,{\mid}\,b\;\;\text{and}\;\;b\,{\mid}\,(-321)\implies d\,{\mid}\,(-321)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Since $-4$ and $321$ are relatively prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, there is an ordinary integer linear combination of $-4$ and $-321$ which equals $1$. For example
$$(80)(-4) + (-1)(-321) = 1$$
Since in the ring $R$, $d\,{\mid}\,(-4)$ and $d\,{\mid}\,(-321)$, it follows that $d$ divides any integer linear combination of $-4$ and $-321$.

In particular, $d\,{\mid}\,1$, so $d$ is a unit in $R$.

Therefore $\gcd(a,b)=1$.